# Recompose from @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a code that adds a new captain to the list and then updates the list and has to redraw it, but it doesn't do that. Although an object is added to the `MutableList`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter", "UnrememberedMutableState",
        "MutableCollectionMutableState"
    )
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            var savedCaptains by remember { mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<Captain>()) }

            Surface (
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState(), enabled = true),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Scaffold (
                    topBar = {
                        CenterAlignedTopAppBar (
                            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                                containerColor = Color.Blue,
                                titleContentColor = Color.White
                            ),
                            title = {
                                Text(text = "Captains", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Column (
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    ) {
                        InputCaptain(list = savedCaptains)
                        CaptainList(this@MainActivity, list = savedCaptains)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun InputCaptain(list: MutableList<Captain>) {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    var ship by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    var description by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = { name = it },
            label = { Text("Captain") }
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = ship,
            onValueChange = { ship = it },
            label = { Text("Ship") }
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = description,
            onValueChange = { description = it },
            label = { Text("Captain description") }
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (name.text.trim().isNotBlank() && ship.text.trim().isNotBlank() && description.text.trim().isNotBlank()) {
                    list.add(Captain(name.text, ship.text, description.text)) // here i'm saving new captain
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Save", color = Color(0x84, 0x5E, 0xC2))
        }
    }
}

// function that shows all saved captains
@Composable
fun CaptainList(activity: Activity, list: MutableList<Captain>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        for (captain in list) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, CaptainCardActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", captain.name)
            intent.putExtra("ship", captain.ship)
            intent.putExtra("description", captain.description)
            intent.putExtra("image", captain.imageName)
            Column (
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                Row (
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable(onClick = {
                            activity.startActivity(intent)
                        })
                        .border(2.dp, Color.LightGray)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    val drawableId = remember(captain.imageName) {
                        context.resources.getIdentifier(
                            if (captain.imageName == "") "ic_action_name" else captain.imageName,
                            "drawable",
                            context.packageName
                        )
                    }
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = drawableId),
                        contentDescription = "Captain image",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(80.dp)
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                    )
                    Column (
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(80.dp)
                            .padding(10.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
                    ) {
                        Text(text = captain.name, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                        Text(text = captain.ship, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the mutable state only recomposes when the object it references to has its identity changed (hashCode), so in this case adding or removing an element to a list doesn't trigger a recomposition.

However, to solve this issue for lists, there's `mutableStateListOf` utility created for this. You can simply change your code to:

```kotlin
var savedCaptains = remember { mutableStateListOf<Captain>() }
```